# C++ console game, glitch re switch statement to move char in 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, switch-statement, 2d

Hi there I am writing a small console game for school. The problem if have is that pushing 'w' and 'a' works (they minus 1 to the row or col element of 2d array) but the 'd' and 's' do not work (they add 1 to the row or col element of 2d array). If you try the code, you will notice that pushing s or d will make the screen glitch out.

Please refer to Move() and Update() of the CGame class.

TY

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const char PLAYER = 'H';
const char WALLS = '=';
const int ROWS = 20;
const int COLS = 50;

//Map class generates map, player and enemies
class CMap{

public:
    char m_cMap[20][50];

    //Map constructor
    CMap(int _row, int _col){



        //Spawn boarders
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
                if (i == 0 || i == ROWS - 1){
                    m_cMap[i][j] = WALLS;
                }else if (j == 0 || j == COLS - 1){
                    m_cMap[i][j] = WALLS;
                }else{
                    m_cMap[i][j] = ' ';
                }
            }

        }

        //Spawn player
        m_cMap[_row][_col] = PLAYER;
    }


};

class CGame{

private:

    void Move(CMap& _map, char _move, int _i, int _j){

        _map.m_cMap[_i][_j] = ' ';

        switch (_move){
        case 'w':
        case 'W':
            _i--;
            break;
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            _i++;
            break;
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            _j--;
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            _j++;
            break;
        default: 
            break;
        }
        _map.m_cMap[_i][_j] = PLAYER;

    }

public:
    //Functions for the main gameloop
    void Update(CMap& _map, char _move){

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
                //Move Player
                if (_map.m_cMap[i][j] == PLAYER){
                    Move(_map, _move, i, j);
                }
                //Move Enemies...
            }
        }

    }



    void Check(CMap _map){}

    void Display(CMap _map){

        system("CLS");

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
                cout << _map.m_cMap[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};




int main(){
    //Generate random numbers for player spawn
    srand(time(0));
    int randRow = (rand() % 17) + 1;
    int randCol = randRow + 20;

    //Instantiate the game and map objects
    CGame game;
    CMap map(randRow, randCol);

    //Game loop
    bool gg = false;
    while (!gg){

        //PlayerController
        char move = 0;
        if (_kbhit){
            move = _getch();
        }


        game.Update(map, move);


        //game.Check(map);
        game.Display(map);


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you move your player you don't break the cycles. And they move it again since the player gets detected again. Modify your Update function like this:

```
//Functions for the main gameloop
void Update(CMap& _map, char _move){
    bool moved = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
            //Move Player
            if (_map.m_cMap[i][j] == PLAYER){
                Move(_map, _move, i, j);
                moved = true;
                break;
            }

            //Move Enemies...
        }
        if (moved)
                break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. But why did it only affect the positive changes to row / col elements and not when subtracting?

Comment: Because when substracting the player goes in to an area already covered by the cycles. When adding it gets detected again either on the same row or same column and gets moved again in the same direction. This unwanted movement happens until the cycles finish iterating the map and the player is moved outside of it.